# Leaving the field

Tags: discussion

Not sure if this is appropriate for Meta, but as a frequent contributor to the site I would like someway to communicate this.  If there is a better way, please let me know and close this post!  I guess this part of the question should go on matheducators.meta.meta?

I am leaving higher education at the end of this semester and will be pursuing work in programming.  So, I may be a much less frequent contributor to this site!

I feel like I have gotten to know a lot of you in this context over the years, and it feels bittersweet to "say goodbye".

Comment: Thanks for saying goodbye!

Comment: I'm sure the upvotes say "best of luck out there" and the downvotes say "sorry to see you go". Thanks for the post!

Comment: I missed this post nearly a year ago. Wishing you all the best! Hope all has gone / is going well with your transition from higher education to programming.

Comment: @JW I have ended up in a bit of a hybrid role!  I am now teaching data science at a company which helps people with PhDs transition to industry.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Am curious to know more but might be getting off topic for the comments section here.

Comment: https://www.erdosinstitute.org/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Just had a look around and saw some nice courses there. Hope you're enjoying teaching in this different context.

Comment: It is **really** nice to be working exclusively with self-motivated people who already have significant academic skills.  I can just focus on content!